# How to connect LineEdit and PushButton in Qt?

Tags: qt

I created a .ui file using Qt Designer and in the file I created a `PushButton` which is disabled initially, I also have a `LineEdit`. I want to connect `LineEdit` and `PushBotton` so that when text changed in `LineEdit` , the `PushButton` will be enabled, But I don't find any such option in Signals and slots. Can anyone help?

Comment: connect `textChanged(const QString & text)` with a custom slot that calls `pushButton->setEnabled(true)`. I think you may want also to check `text.isEmpty()` into that slot

Comment: @Miki I am using Qt 4.8 Designer , I am creating ui files not coding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can / have to write your custom slots... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964869/qt-designer-how-to-add-custom-slot-and-code-to-a-button

Comment: Do you say there is no way we can do it from Designer?

Comment: I'm saying that I don't think that you have a _standard_ slot that fits your needs, so write your own. You should still be able to connect to that slot in the Designer.

Comment: Can we add slots to designer? I mean can I create a slot to the Designer?

Comment: We can create custom slots to the Designer.   Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-create-a-custom-slot-in-qt4-designer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write a custom slot (which is pretty easy).

Add this to your MainWindow declaration (**.h** file):

```
private slots:
    void checkInput(const QString &text);
```

Your **.cpp** file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(checkInput(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::checkInput(const QString &text)
{
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(!text.isEmpty());
}
```

To add this slot to Qt Designer, do the following:

- Right click on your MainWindow, "Change signals/slots";
- Add your custom slot ("Plus" button) by entering **checkInput()**;
- After this you will be able to connect your custom slot via Qt Designer.

Comment: How can I add this to Designer??

Comment: When I right click on the Form I am not getting any option to change signals/slots.

Comment: You can also get this dialog by pressing "Edit..." button in the "Configure Connection" window when connecting signals/slots (F4).

Comment: This slot is a MainWindow member, that is why it works for MainWindow. For this particular case you'll need to connect LineEdit and MainWindow (not your button) signal and slot.

Comment: And how can I define the slot() when I create one for MainWindow.

Comment: What do you me by "define the slot()"? When connecting `LineEdit` to `MainWindow` via Qt Designer, the `Edit...` button should be enabled.

Comment: Yes, there I am adding slots but how to define those slots.

Comment: Slot definition is already in the answer. The slot is declared in the header file and defined as a usual member function in the cpp. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Qt 5, you generally don't need trivial private slots and should use lambdas instead:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [this](const QString & text) {
      ui->pushButton->setEnabled(!text.isEmpty());
    });
    ...
}
```